# How to get a document object from a file object in a Google-Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

My problem is that I have a number of Google documents (docs) and each has a table of contents. I want to grab the TOC's and place them in another document. This should be easy, but I have run into a snag.

I can grab all of files in a folder with:

```
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('yourfolder');
  var contents = folder.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.DOCUMENT);
```

This gives me an array of files as the variable 'contents'

Great.

I also know that

```
  var TOC = **doc**.getAs(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS)
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get a document object from a file object or alternately how to get an array of documents in a folder rather than an array of files.

I have searched for an answer and not only on this site. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocsList` and `DocumentApp` have at least one method in common which is that they have access to the `ID` of documents so it is quite straightforward to pass this ID parameter from one method to the other.

This code demonstrates :

```
function myFunction() {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('yourfolder');
  var contents = folder.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.DOCUMENT);
  var docObject = [];
  for(var c in contents){
    docObject.push(DocumentApp.openById(contents[c].getId()));
  }
  Logger.log(docObject);// now you have an array of DocumentApp objects
}
```